How to parse chat from group with telethon python
Can't parse chat from a group. A group has a lot of chats and i need to parse one of them, not all the group. The. group has an id such as -10034123324 but chat in that group has id -10034123324_4329. When i'm trying to parse this chat i have an error:
return utils.get_input_peer(channels.chats[0])
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

-10034123324_4329 is not a valid channel identifier. Where did you obtain this value from?

it's an example
